# How can I write my Firebase Security Rules if I need non-logged in users to be able to read and write?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm brand new to Firebase, and I'm having trouble with my security rules. I recently took over a project and the current rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

This obviously is not secure. The app allows users (logged in) to enter a customer phone number, and it uses Twilio to send those customers a text asking them to review the user's product. The customers don't have to do any logging in - they can just click the link from Twilio, enter their star rating, and are given the option to go to other review sites.

In the Firebase DB, the customer (and the review they are entering) is a child of the user that entered them. Based on the docs, I don't think I can make a rule that users must be authenticated because that will be applied to all children (the customers) as well.

Do I need to add Anonymous Authentication to my app to create an anonymous uid for each customer? Is there an easier way to secure it?

Here's an example of the Json export from Firebase:

```
{
      "profiles" : {
        "User1_UID" : {
          "guests" : {
            "guest-id-here" : {
              "createdOn" : "2018-06-28T16:23:53.793Z",
              "firstName" : "",
              "id" : "id-here",
              "lastName" : "",
              "phone" : "",
              "ratingLeft" : true,
              "reviewSite" : true,
              "reviewSiteClicked" : {
                "facebook" : true,
                "google" : true,
                "other" : false,
                "tripadvisor" : true,
                "yelp" : true
              },
              "reviewSiteClickedOn" : "2018-06-28T16:26:46.237Z",
              "reviewedOn" : "2018-06-28T16:25:22.996Z",
              "starRating" : "5"
            },
            "guest2-id-here" : {
              "createdOn" : "2018-07-15T18:57:52.171Z",
              "firstName" : "Joe",
              "id" : "guest2-id",
              "lastName" : "Schmoe",
              "phone" : "+1234567890",
              "ratingLeft" : false,
              "reviewedOn" : "",
              "starRating" : ""
            },
            }
          },
      "User2_UID" : {
      "guests" : {
        "guest-id-here" : {
          "ratingLeft" : true
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Please put your data structure here...

Comment: Updated post to show the database structure.

Comment: Is your App using `Firebase Auth`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Auth. Account Holders can sign in with Email/password. Guests that leave reviews do not log in.

Comment: Logged in users are identified by their UID, and how are you identifying the guests?

Comment: Guests get an ID when they are created by the logged in users, and that ID is included in the URL that gets sent out by Twilio. The URL looks like: http://5stars.q4launch.com/rating/USERID/GUESTID. The guest doesn't have a username or password though. They can just click on the link in the text, make their review selection, and it gets saved.

Comment: Where do the 'Guests' leave the rating? Could you post the DB structure of that?

Comment: You can actually make a rule to have users be authenticated and only apply the read/write = true on the guests part of your structure.